# How do i find t in these questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[The questions are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evxya.jpg) Initial value- 69900

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Maybe you could type the questions instead of referring to them in a link.

Comment: I don't think asking us to solve your homework is the goal of this forum. I would have tried Yahoo Answers first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note - this certainly isn't algebraic topology.

Anyway, you could do something like this for the first one:
$$69000 - 69000 \times \frac{15}{100} = 69000 \times \frac{85}{100}$$ 
is the value of the car after one year since the car loses $15\%$ value every year. Next year it will lose another $15\%$ so it's value will then be:
$$ 69000 \times \frac{85}{100} \times \frac{85}{100} = 69000 \times \big(\frac{85}{100}\big)^2$$
This means you want to find $t$ such that 
$$69000 \times \big(\frac{85}{100}\big)^t = 5000$$
So manipulating this
$$t = \frac{\text{ln}\big(\frac{5000}{69000}\big)}{\text{ln}\big(\frac{85}{100}\big)} = 16.2$$

Comment: Please consider not giving such a detailed and complete answer to a question that shows absolutely no effort.